# How to open/toggle to the 10th screen session in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, gnu-screen

I have a screen session where in i have created 10 sessions .

I use the below key combination to toggle to the active screen session attached.

ctrl + a + number 0 to 9

Ctrl-a 0-9  Go to a window numbered 0-9

i have created a 10th session now

ctrl-a 10 will end up to the screen session 1.

how to toggle to the 10th session ??

work around for the same is , go to the 9th session
Ctrl-a 9
and then ctrl-n will lead me to the 10th session.

Link i referred to learn screen in linux

http://www.kb.indiana.edu/data/acuy.html

Answer (score 7):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> then <kbd>'</kbd> (apostrophe) will display a prompt and let you enter the number or name of a window to switch to.

To rename a window, use <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Shift+A</kbd>. (<kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> to remove the old name before typing a new one.)

Other ways to switch windows include:

- <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> to return to the window you were looking at before
- <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to go to the next in sequence
- <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to go to the previous in sequence
- <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> to select from a list (thanks stan and dogbane!)

Answer (score 3):

I think some of these can open a windows list:

```
ctrl+a "    #window list
ctrl+a w    #window list
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `C-a "` which will show you a list of all windows and you can then select the 10th one

Alternatively, go to the 9th window and then use `C-a n` to go to the 10th.

Answer (score 0):

According to screen's manual page, you can add the following lines to your `~/.screenrc` file:

```
bind -c demo1 0 select 10
bind -c demo1 1 select 11
bind -c demo1 2 select 12
bindkey "^B" command -c demo1
```

makes `C-b 0` select window 10, `C-b 1` window 11, etc. Alternatively, you can use:

```
bind -c demo2 0 select 10
bind -c demo2 1 select 11
bind -c demo2 2 select 12
bind - command -c demo2
```

makes "C-a - 0" select window 10, "C-a - 1" window 11, etc.